# how to find a particular tag in a string, get a value from it and then replace the string with PHP

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, str-replace, preg-match-all

I have a string like this:

```
$string = 'some text <div class"myClass" path="myPath_1">some content</div> some text
           some text <div class"myClass" path="myPath_2">some content</div> some text...';
```

I need to get the value of the attribute path for all occurrences:

```
$path = array('myPath_1','myPath_2');
```

Once I have this I have to replace the whole div:

```
<div class"myClass" path="myPath_1">some content</div>
```

with an image tag:

```
<img src="myPath_1">
```

How could I go about this?

Comment: you could use DOM to parse it, traverse it and replace stuff in it. but it requires the html to be almost flawless to go through the parsing process of the PHP dom interpreter.

Comment: Is your div contains the same class all over, And only the path is changed?

Comment: Yes, the path attribute is the only thing that changes

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string = 'some text <div class"myClass" path="myPath_1">some content</div> some text
           some text <div class"myClass" path="myPath_2">some content</div> some text...';
$matches = array();
$matches = preg_match_all('/path="([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)"/', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$paths = array_map(function($m){
    return $m[0];
}, $matches);
var_dump($paths);
// array("myPath_1", "myPath_2")
?>
```

Here I am using the regex string `path="([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)"` together with PHP's [preg_match_all function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), which should match your paths. `path`, however is not a valid html attribute, I don't know if you are aware. Consider changing it to `data-path`.

I know you are asking how to replace your div tags, but your current html is malformed. `<div class"myClass"` should be `<div class="myClass"` instead. However, you should be able to do something like:

```
<?php
$string = 'some text <div class"myClass" path="myPath_1">some content</div> some text
           some text <div class"myClass" path="myPath_2">some content</div> some text...';
$new_string = preg_replace('<div class=?"myClass" path="([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)">[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+</div>','<img src="$1">');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with regex:

```
$pattern = '/<div([a-zA-Z0-9 ="]+)path="([^"]+)">([^<]+)<\/div>/';
echo preg_replace($pattern, '<img src="$2" />', $string);
```